# Do you need to set viewport fit=cover to use css env() variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps

According to this [mdn web docs article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) it seems you need to first set the viewport meta tag before using any env() variables. Is it also true that viewport fit=cover attribute is mandatory?

it seems I can access env() variables - such as safe-area-inset-* - without setting viewport fit=cover attribute OR having added the viewport meta tag altogether.

Comment: Also have a look at the examples - you can click on that arrow-coming-out-of-rectangle icon to fullscreen the examples and go into your browser developer tools. Their examples also use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` for example. They were more like saying to use a meta viewport tag in general, the wording is unclear on their part while the examples don't use fit=cover.